# What's the most efficient and reliable method to test CSS design in multiple legacy browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, frontend

I'd be very interested to hear what professional developers think about this, particularly frontend developers.

How do you go about testing your designs in multiple browsers? Do you use virtual machines, each with a different version of Internet Explorer installed? What is your setup/workflow?

So, what's the most efficient and reliable way to test a design in several legacy web browsers?

Thank you.

Comment: multiple Vms each with the browsers we want to test. Alternatively there are such things as [Browserling](http://browserling.com/)

Comment: [BroswerShots](http://browsershots.org/) is an interesting concept, but from my experience the free usage isn't great.

Answer (score 4):

I mostly use [Spoon virtualization](http://spoon.net/browsers/). They removed IE from the service aftyer Microsoft told them to however it's still a good service for testing other browsers/versions.

For IE I tend to use the [Microsoft provided IE VMs](http://microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en).

If you need virtualization product then [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is pretty good and free.

I've also just discovered [Browserling](http://browserling.com/) which does something similar to Spoon virtualization and has support for multiple IE versions.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle's [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) is free. I have the following VMs set-up:

- Windows XP - IE6, Firefox 3
- Windows XP - IE7, Firefox 4
- Windows Vista - IE8

Really, I don't test older versions of Firefox, Chrome, or Safari. All three of those browsers are on quick update cycles now and the push their updates almost immediately. The chance that users are still using an older version of those is much less than those using Internet Explorer.

Even now, I don't really test in IE6 anymore (thank god), but I know this is different depending on the audience of your website.

Really, if you can get away with it, do your basic testing in IE 7, 8, 9 and the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. Don't go completely out of your way to fix layout issues in older IEs; If you can get the information you want from the site, then the site is functioning. If someone complains about the site not looking exactly right, recommend they upgrade or switch browsers. "I can't upgrade from IE6 because my company uses it" is not really a valid excuse anymore with Chrome and Firefox being as light weight as they are, unless their computer admins have things completely locked down.

Comment: Yes VirtualBox is excellent. You say "depending on the audience", would you say it's important to test a UK college web site in IE6 or not so much? It's 10 years old, but yet netmarkshare says 10% of idiots still run it.

Comment: I'd say no. What I meant by audience is that some companies had software products they purchased back when IE6 was out. These companies are so heavily invested in their product, they either can't or won't move away from them or IE6. Out of those 10% of idiots you mention, probably 90% of them don't have a choice.

Comment: Just as a continuation, I run and manage several websites at an University. We no longer test or support IE6.

Answer (score 1):

IE Tester allows to see web from ie5  till ie9.

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: Thanks Ēriks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how legacy you wonna go but there is also [Adobe browser lab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html).